# Why isnt the move method working in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java and I just want to know how to move a picture in a JFrame.
Ive created a JLabel and added an Icon using the design tab, and added that label to a panel, and I want it to move when a button is pressed.

```
private void jPanel2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    switch (evt.getKeyCode())
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            move(0, 10);

            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            move(0, -10);

            break; 
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            move(-10, 0);

            break; 
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            move(10, 0);
            break;
        default:
            move(0, 10);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see your `move` method at least.

Comment: Actually its not my method, its in the JPanel class

Comment: Ah I see. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Is the above method called by a listener? Is the according Listener added to your frame somewhere??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do but:

> @Deprecated
>   public void move(int x,
>                      int y)
>
> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by setLocation(int, int).

so it would be better to call `setLocation()` on the component you want to move.

If you have your JPanel attached to another panel the Layout of the parent may let setting a new position have no effect. Same if you use it as a ContentPane for a JFrame.

If you want to move your Winwow/JFrame you will have to call the method on the Frame and not the panel.

Comment: If it helped you it would be nice to accept the answer